# Prove that $ 2 \vert AD \vert \geq \sqrt {3} ( \vert AB \vert + \vert BC \vert + \vert CD \vert ) $

Tags: geometry, inequality, euclidean-geometry

Let $A$, $X$ and $D$ be points on a line, with $X$ between $A$ and $D$. Let $B$ be a point such that $ \angle ABX > 120^{\circ} $, and $C$ a point on the line between $B$ and $X$. Prove that $$ 2 \vert AD \vert \geq \sqrt {3} ( \vert AB \vert + \vert BC \vert + \vert CD \vert ) $$

The first thing I tried was to convert all the points into vectors,  but I have struggled to place any useful restrictions on the value of $B$. Other than that I have made little to no progress. Anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Let $\alpha = \angle XAB$ and $\beta = \angle XDC$ and $\gamma = \angle AXC$.  Then $AD = \cos \alpha AB + \cos \gamma BC + \cos \beta CD$ and $\alpha + \gamma \le 60$ and $\beta < \gamma$.  Does that help?

Comment: @fleablood Perfect answer, thanks. The fact that $CX$ cancels out when multiplied by $ \cos \alpha $ and $ \cos (180- \alpha ) $ is a nice touch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $ BC+CD \leq BX+XD $ by the triangle inequality, hence we may assume $X\equiv C$.
On the other hand $AB+BX\leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}AX$.
[image]

Let $Y$ be the point such that $AXY$ is equilateral and $Y,B$ lie on opposite sides of $AX$. Let $B'$ be the intersection between $YB$ and the circumcircle $\Gamma$ of $AXY$. We have $AB+BX\leq AB'+B'X$ and by [Ptolemy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem) $AB'+B'X = YB'$, that is $\leq$ than the diameter of $\Gamma$, that is exactly $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}AX$.

It follows that

$$ AB+BC+CD \leq AB+BX+XD \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}AX+XD \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(AX+XD)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} AD.$$